Is it secure to perform distributed verification of Schnorr’s identification protocol using MPC?
Is it feasible and secure to perform distributed verification of Schnorr’s identification protocol using an MPC protocol over an elliptic group (as in https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/889 and https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/768.pdf), such that $s \cdot G = R + e \cdot P$, where only the public key $P$ and the random element $R$ are held in secret-shared form? the result of $ +  \cdot $ will be revealed, and the equality test is performed in the clear.
For our use case, we need to hide the clients' public keys (i.e., $P_i$) from the MPC servers, while at the same time allowing clients to prove their ownership of the keys to the servers through the signatures $s_i$.
